# Cannot downgrade App Engine release

Tags: google-app-engine

Recently I've found out App Engine 1.9.1 has a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693955/scope-not-allowed-when-calling-api-method-from-api-explorer) which however does not occur in version 1.8.9 and below. I am developing my applications with Eclipse and the Google Plugin for Eclipse. In the Google properties of the project I switched back to 1.8.9. If I work locally I can see that it is using version 1.8.9 (the bug does not occur) however when I deploy to App Engine no matter what I do it will still run on 1.9.1. I even tryed to create a new project/application from scratch, still 1.9.1. I even deleted SDKs 1.9.1 and 1.9.0 from my system but nothing seems to help. What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't control the version in production. It runs on Google servers and isn't deployed as part of your app.

Comment: That sounds quite strange... It basically means that I can't develop anything until they fix the bug or I find a workaround (which does not exist). Are you absolutely sure about this?

Comment: Yes, of course. That is in fact *the whole point* of a service like GAE: you don't manage the environment, you manage your app only. (I doubt however there is a bug: probably a change in behaviour.)

Comment: Well in the [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) they say nothing about it so I supposed it was a bug. In any case it's something that used to work and doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @raz3r have you filed a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the cloud world where some parameters slip from your hand no matter how hard you try...

Indeed, you have no control over the AppEngine version that will be used to run your application in production. In fact, if you look carefully in the list of instance on your cloud console, you will see sometimes that some instances use an AppEngine version that is not even publicly available at the moment.